# OUYA and Unity set up problems

Tags: unity, ouya

I'm having trouble with the Unity / OUYA plugin.

I'm using Unity 4 with the latest update on a Windows 7 machine.

When I open the starter kit and try to compile the plugin I get the following error:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

And if I try to Build and Run I get this error:

> Error building Player: ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

I'm stumped, I've gone through lots of forum posts here and on stackoverflow and I can't seem to resolve it.

My environment variables look like this:

```
PATH - C:\Users\dave\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools;
       C:\Users\dave\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\platform-tools\

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\
```

Everything in the OUYA Panel is white

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033609/ouya-and-unity-set-up-problems). Pick a site to keep and delete the other instance of the question please.

Comment: done, didn't realise this site existed until after I'd posted the question on stack - no spam intended!

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of the Unity plugin, the Java/Native plugin comes pre-compiled. So there's no longer the need to build the Java or native portion of the plugin in the OUYA Panel. Just import the Core plugin and you'll be ready to File->Build and Run for the Android platform.

You can find the latest Core plugin here:
https://github.com/ouya/ouya-sdk-examples/releases/tag/Unity-OuyaSDK-Core

Most recently the core plugin adds support for your Unity plugin on Forge TV.

Answer (score -1):

Don't have an OUYA so just a wild guess, but it might be a memory problem. Try checking https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF29/Fix+Out+of+Memory+errors+by+Increasing+Available+Memory and see if that helps. Perhaps you have to increase the assigned memory by adding some parameter value.

Comment: What made you conclude it's a memory issue? The error states there is something wrong with the paths.